# Log In controller looking in wrong directory

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a VS2013, ASP.NET, MVC program that works fine on the development box. But when it is moved to the production box I receive the following error when trying to sign on as a new user - Programname.Controllers.LoginController.LoadSecurityInformation(LoginModel loginModel) in c:\Users\Username\Desktop\Programname\Controllers\LoginController.cs

I think it is looking for the login controller on the development box. We manually add users to the SQL database. The program works fine for users who were entered in the database before the move to production, but when we put new users in the SQL database we receive the error above.  What is wrong here?

Comment: Need some code to have the remotest clue what you mean.

Comment: does that path exist on the production server?

Comment: Tim - No. That is the path to my project on the "development" box. That path does not exist on the "production" box. In our shop we transfer all the project folders/files to the production box without publishing.  [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Programname.Controllers.LoginController.LoadSecurityInformation(LoginModel loginModel) in c:\Users\uasername\Desktop\Programname\Controllers\LoginController.cs

Comment: What code do you need Adam?

Comment: How are you "moving" the "code" to the production box? How is the project set up on the development box (using IIS or the developer web server)?